# Get post terms from multiple custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy

In order to assign post_tags and custom_taxonomies from a post to a class, this is what I've been trying to do.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, array( 'post_tag', 'custom' );

if ( $terms ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $termString .= $term->slug . ' ';
    }
}

<div class="taxonomies here">content</div>
```

For some reason this doesn´t work, seems like get_the_terms does not support arrays for multiple taxonomies. How can this be worked around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I came across this from another question:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, get_object_taxonomies('post') );
```

and it works.